# How can I include a run_date to code in my airflow Dag?

Tags: python, airflow

I'm new in Python.
How can I name my table which will include a date in the name?

```
with DAG("inform_status",
         schedule_interval="55 17 * * 1-5",
         start_date=days_ago(1),
         catchup=False,
         tags=["Adb"]) as dag:

    task5 = TelegramOperator(
    task_id='task5',  
    telegram_conn_id='telegram_conn',  
    text='Report of {Timestamp}_table_name:
      {Query_result}',    
    chat_id=telegram_chat_id,      
    dag=dag    
)
```

Comment: You can use jinja template. Here is the reference: https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/templates-ref.html

Answer (score 0):

You can utilize the ds macro, which stands for "datestamp." This macro provides the execution date in the 'YYYY-MM-DD' format.

```
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.telegram_operator import TelegramOperator
from airflow.utils.dates import days_ago

with DAG("inform_status",
         schedule_interval="55 17 * * 1-5",
         start_date=days_ago(1),
         catchup=False,
         tags=["Adb"]) as dag:

    task5 = TelegramOperator(
        task_id='task5',
        telegram_conn_id='telegram_conn',
        text=f'Report of {ds}_table_name: {Query_result}',
        chat_id=telegram_chat_id,
        dag=dag
    )
```